# Finding the triggering statement

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I want to write a trigger in MySQL, which will record down the statement that causes the trigger to fire. I know how to do this in Oracle:

```
n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
for i in 1..n loop
  stmt := stmt || sql_text(i);
end loop;
```

But I can't find an equivalent in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL text of the statement that caused the trigger to be fired might be available in the `processlist` table in `information_schema` database.

e.g. maybe something like this (not tested)

```
DECLARE ls_pl_info VARCHAR(65536);

SELECT pl.info
  INTO ls_pl_info  
  FROM information_schema.processlist pl
 WHERE pl.id = CONNECTION_ID() ;
```

-or maybe-

```
SELECT t.processlist_info
  INTO ls_pl_info  
  FROM performance_schema.threads t
 WHERE t.processlist_id = CONNECTION_ID() ;
```

(What I'm not sure about, and haven't tested, is whether the info column will contain the SQL text of the statement that fired the trigger, or if that's going to show the text of the *current* statement, which is accessing the processlist table.)

But that's the closest I can come; I don't believe the text of the statement that caused the trigger to fire is available within the trigger.

References:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/processlist-table.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/thread-information.html

NOTE: If `general_log` is enabled (which isn't usually enabled on our systems; we usually only enable it temporarily to gather info for a small timeframe...) but I don;t think the triggering statement will be available in the general log until after it completes, which means after the fired triggers are completed.

Another option would be the binary log (if binary logging is enabled). But getting to that from inside a trigger seems like it would be messily over complicated.

Comment: It doesn't work! The statement saved is the select statement you wrote, not the issuing update statement.

Comment: I don't see a syntax error in the SQL I posted. Obviously, there's limitations on the sequences of statements in a trigger... the DECLARE statements need to be before other statements... the user has to have SELECT privilege on `information_schema.processlist` table,  and with a semicolon in the body of the trigger, we need to specify a different statement delimiter for the CREATE TRIGGER statement, ..

Comment: I wasn't sure what the `info` column would contain, since we are running a SELECT to retrieve a row from a table, I was thinking that SELECT would be in processlist table, not the triggering statement. Maybe someone else has a clever way to get the SQL text of the statement that cause the trigger to be fired, from within the trigger.) But it's not at all clear why we need that in the trigger; what the trigger is going to do with it. Maybe there's some other way to solve the problem we are trying to solve, without the actual text of the SQL statement.

Comment: MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE ls_pl_info VARCHAR(65536); SELECT pl.info INTO ls_pl_info FRO' at line 1

Comment: Despite all the errors, I solved my problem, without knowing the offending statement. This solution isn't correct, but it's a good starting point. So I will accept it.

Comment: Zirui Wang: The syntax I posted is only valid in the context of a MySQL stored program (e.g. TRIGGER, FUNCTION, PROCEDURE) because that's the only context a `DECLARE` statement is valid. Since MySQL restricts a TRIGGER from returning resultsets, a SELECT statement inside a trigger either has to be defined as a CURSOR, or if we are wanting just one row, we can do a SELECT ... INTO. We can use either local variables or user defined variables as the target of the INTO, but in the context of stored program, we'd prefer to use local variables over a user-defined variables.